# How to InvokeMember on a previous InvokeMember result?

Tags: c#

I have to implement a COM action in a C#. The COM object is SSOEngine from Evidian.

I have the VB.NET sample. I have to translate into C#.

In VB.NET, I can do the job with that code :

```
Dim oSSO, oApp
oSSO = CreateObject("SSOEngine.SSOEngine")
oApp = oSSO.GetApplication2("myApp", "MyPassword", 0)
return oApp.LoginId(0)
```

In C#, I do the following code

```
System.Type objTypeSSOEngine = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SSOEngine.SSOEngine");
object instSSOEngine = Activator.CreateInstance(objTypeSSOEngine);
object o = objTypeSSOEngine.InvokeMember("GetApplication2",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, 
            instSSOEngine, new object[] { "myApp", "MyPassword", 0 });
```

I am blocked on the oApp.LoginId(0) line...
Do you know how to do another InvokeMember on the o object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) in case of if you are using .net 4

```
System.Type objTypeSSOEngine = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SSOEngine.SSOEngine");
dynamic instSSOEngine = Activator.CreateInstance(objTypeSSOEngine);
dynamic oApp = objTypeSSOEngine.GetApplication2("myApp", "MyPassword", 0 );
return oApp.LoginId(0);
```

In case of if not, you can add COM reference(add reference -> COM in visual studio) and Visual Studio will generate managed Intermediate dll with suitable classes and interfaces  for you

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**.NET 2.0 -> 3.5**

If you aware of the `type` of the object return from the  `GetApplication2` call, just cast it to known type and call a functions you need.

```
object o = objTypeSSOEngine.InvokeMember("GetApplication2",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, 
            instSSOEngine, new object[] { "myApp", "MyPassword", 0 });

KnownType tp = o as KnownType; 
if(tp!=null)
    tp .LoginId(0)
```

**.NET 4.0**

Use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

*a pseudocode*

```
System.Type objTypeSSOEngine = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("SSOEngine.SSOEngine");
dynamic instSSOEngine = Activator.CreateInstance(objTypeSSOEngine);
dynamic oApp = instSSOEngine.GetApplication2("myApp", "MyPassword", 0)
return oApp.LoginId(0)
```

Something like this...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot all!

I am not in .NET 4.0, so I can't use Dynamic... (I didn't know about that 'variant' type...that's great!)...

also I can't use .NET 4.0...

I know that the type of the return object is SSOApplication, but I need to create a reference to the C++ dll to reference it I think...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the **dynamic** type. [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

You can cast ANY object to this type and you don't need to use Reflection.